# Running a program from a past/future time in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell

I am trying to write an automated test for an engine which connects to a license server, one of the things that I want to test is how the engine will react when the license is expired while the engine is running. I am using nodejs to manually start this engine by running some commands on cmd to call the engine start script (ie/startengine.bat or ./startengine.sh), I was wondering if there is a way to alter the time at which the engine is started using nodejs. For example, if the license is set to expire on December 2nd of 2018, is there a way to start the engine with a "fake" time of December 1st 23:59?

I tried using timekeeper node package and when i do:

```
var time = new Date(1569902400);
timeKeeper.travel(time); 
var today = new Date();
console.log(today.getDay());
```

I seem to get the date that I want but when I start my engine, it doesn't seem to be using this time... are there anything that I am missing or is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Cause the 19th January 1970 was a Monday. And today is Monday too... ;)

Comment: well actually first of all, the timestamp that i put in (1569902400) is for october 1st of 2019, which just so happen to be a tuesday. Secondly, the new Date works it's just that when i start the engine it's not seeing this date

Comment: @ted [thats funny](http://jsbin.com/limitawivi/edit?console). Probably you forgot some zeros

Comment: oh my bad, i took the epoch time instead of the one in millisecond :P although the engine is still not starting in the defined time as the timestamp is still 2017-12-05T20:17:25.562Z. Any suggestions?